# Execute action after a defined time since level start

Tags: time, sprite-kit

I'm creating a game with sprite-kit and my question is if there is a simple way to execute an action after a certain time since level start. I know i can define a timer a count time having an if statement with my period of time, but i think sprite-kit should have a timer for scene or something like that. But i haven't found any info about this.

Any idea ?

Comment: waitForDuration SKAction in a sequence with your desired action, run it when scene is created (ie in init)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're trying to use an SKAction when you start the game you can do the following.

```
SKAction *timer = [SKAction waitForDuration: 10];
SKAction *someAction = //put some action here;
SKAction *finalAction = [SKAction sequence:@[timer, someAction]];
```

With that, "someAction" will be executed right after 10 seconds.